# Is the Fargues–Fontaine curve proper?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

It is well known that Fontaine's curve $X=\bigoplus_{k\geq0}B_{\text{cris}}^{+,\varphi=p^k}$ is a Noetherian irreducible complete scheme of dimension $1$. And completeness means that the degree formula $\sum_{x\in X}\text{ord}_x(f)=0$ holds for all $f$ in the function field as in Definition 2.6 of [Morrow's survey](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/TEXTES/Exp1150-Morrow.pdf).

I want to ask if this curve $X$ is proper over $B_{\text{cris}}^{+,\varphi=1}$? Does this property have some relation with completeness?

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Sorry, I have changed them. $\varphi$ is the Frobenius action as I used in this question. And maybe I haven't seen $\psi$ in $p$-adic Hodge theory...

Comment: A proper morphism is of finite type by definition. If I understand these things correctly, $X$ is not.

Comment: Maybe the Fargues-Fontaine curve could satisfy something like the valuative criterion of properness.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly  Bonjour! How to see $X\rightarrow \text{Spec}B_{\text{cris}}^{+,\varphi=1} $ is not of finite type?

Comment: @Sssss $B_{cris}^{+,\varphi=1} = \mathbf{Q}_p$

Comment: @LaurentBerger But I still can’t see why $X$ is not of finite type over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Could you explain this? You are an expert in $p$-adic Hodge theory, so I’m sure you know this. Thanks!